# How to Generate a List of Things with Comma-separated Values in One Column/Cell

Tags: list, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used to be able to make a list using FILTER and ISNUMBER(MATCH()) from a table with the old method.

[image]

Now, the table is populated using a new method and I find myself unable to figure out how to generate the same list; I initially think that I need some kind of "bridge" for the FILTER and ISNUMBER(MATCH()) to be able to generate the list, but I couldn't figure out how to make the "bridge", let alone the formula to generate such list without the bridge.

[image]

I humbly ask for help and ideas.

Here's the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/121igjaxcgFLC1SMWG5nz133BC0hVWiXm7kulEJS99Oc/edit?usp=sharing) to the Google Sheets file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=query(index(split(flatten(A2:index(A:A,match(2,1/(A:A<>"")))&"|"&map(B2:index(B:B,match(2,1/(B:B<>""))),lambda(z,split(z,",")))),"|")),"where Col2 is not null")
```